# Debug Assertion Failed on \$InstallDir\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\appgui3.cpp, line 385 when loading MFC view

Tags: c, wpf, mfc

In my task, I have to load a MFC view in WPF windows. When I run the code, there is an error show this:

Debug assertion failed at appgui3.cpp, line 385:

```
  BOOL CWinApp::EnableTaskbarInteraction(BOOL bEnable) 
{
    if(AfxGetMainWnd() != NULL)
    {
        ASSERT(FALSE);
        **TRACE0("Windows 7 taskbar interacrion must be called before creation of main window.\n");**
        return FALSE;
    }

    m_bTaskbarInteractionEnabled = bEnable;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you explicitly calling `CWinApp::EnableTaskbarInteraction` or is it being called from within MFC?

Comment: I called it within MFC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a main window. Creating a view inside a WPF window still requires a frame window. 
And as long as you have a EXE you need a main frame window for some frame tasks like task bar interaction. As long as you have no mainframe window there is no window the taskbar can interact with.